# Manage Teams Files permissions programmatically

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm creating MS Teams via Graph API and adding external users to the Teams. Currently, these externals can delete and upload files under the Files tab of the Team. They should only be able to read the files as the management of the files should be left to the owner(s) of the Team. I'm able to get the sharepointId of the Team; I'm not sure where to go from there.

```
# Get the SharePoint site ID associated with the team
    get_sharepoint_url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group_id}/sites/root"
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    response = requests.get(get_sharepoint_url, headers=headers)
    sharepoint_id = response.json().get('id')
    print(lineInfo(), f'SharePoint ID: {sharepoint_id}')

    # Define the endpoint URL for updating SharePoint permissions
    update_permissions_url =...
```

Comment: To restrict external users from deleting and uploading files under the Files tab of the Team, you need to update the SharePoint permissions for the associated SharePoint site of the Team. After retrieving the SharePoint site ID using the Graph API, you can use the SharePoint REST API to update the permissions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/set-custom-permissions-on-a-list-by-using-the-rest-interface